# Changing colours on ggplot2 for geom_smooth with non-default aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a glmer.nb model on ggplot2 as below:

```
#plot modeled data
p <- ggplot(avg.slice, aes(x =slice.depth.DB, y=MP.kg)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = pallete12, width = slice.width.DB) +     
        scale_x_reverse() + 
          coord_flip() +  
            geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=MP.kg-ci, ymax=MP.kg+ci)) +
              geom_smooth(data=site.pred, aes(x=Depth, y=pred.site, color = Station), stat = "identity") +   #adds model from predictions
                  xlab ("Sediment Depth (cm)") +
                    ylab (expression(paste("Microplastic Concentration (microplastic kg"^"-1"*")")))
```

Which yields the following graph:
[image: Plot]

I would like to change the colours of the stations but I can't figure out how. I've tried:

```
pallete_station<-colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12, "Paired"))

pallete13<-pallete_station(13)

p + scale_color_manual(pallete13)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in f(...) : argument "values" is missing, with no default
```

I think the problem is due to the stations being mapped on a different `aes` to the default, but I can't figure out how to adjust for this.

Comment: `values` is not the first argument in `scale_color_manual`, so you need to use it explicitly: `scale_color_manual(values = pallete13)`.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something simple. Thanks.